# 2 GB of memory in 1 GB system is a problem?

Tags: windows, upgrade, memory, memory-limit

I just installed 2 1 Gig sticks into my friend's machine, thinking that it would take all the 2 GBs. Unfortunately, according to Dell's website, it says the maximum amount of memory accessible to the machine is arbitrarily set to 1 GB! The system indeed reports having 1 GB of memory accessible to it, but I'm worried that having 2 GB in there might break something. Are my fears reasonable? Should I buy two 512 MB sticks instead?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem. Your system should be able to cope with one 1GB stick - in fact it already is!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it. The biggest thing that I can see is that you're wasting 1GB of memory.